# How to use the differential quadrature method to solve second order differential equations with Dirichlet boundary conditions？

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a second-order differential equation with Dirichlet Boundary Conditions shown below

$\begin{array}{l}
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
\frac{{dr}}{{dt}} = v\\
m\frac{{dv}}{{dt}} = f\sin \left( {\omega t} \right)
\end{array} \right.\\
r\left( 0 \right) = 0,r\left( 1 \right) = 10
\end{array}$

Apply the principle of differential quadrature

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{a_{11}}{r_1} + {a_{12}}{r_2} +  \cdots {a_{1n}}{r_n} = {v_1}\\
{a_{11}}{v_1} + {a_{12}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{1n}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_1})}}{m}\\
{a_{21}}{r_1} + {a_{22}}{r_2} +  \cdots {a_{2n}}{r_n} = {v_2}\\
{a_{21}}{v_1} + {a_{22}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{2n}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_2})}}{m}\\
 \vdots \\
{a_{n1}}{r_1} + {a_{n2}}{r_2} +  \cdots {a_{nn}}{r_n} = {v_n}\\
{a_{n1}}{v_1} + {a_{n2}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{nn}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_n})}}{m}
\end{array} \right.$

Apply boundary conditions

$\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
{r_1} = 0\\
{a_{11}}{v_1} + {a_{12}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{1n}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_1})}}{m}\\
{a_{21}}{r_1} + {a_{22}}{r_2} +  \cdots {a_{2n}}{r_n} = {v_2}\\
{a_{21}}{v_1} + {a_{22}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{2n}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_2})}}{m}\\
 \vdots \\
{r_n} = 10\\
{a_{n1}}{v_1} + {a_{n2}}{v_2} +  \cdots {a_{nn}}{v_n} = \frac{{f\sin (\omega {t_n})}}{m}
\end{array} \right.$

At this step, I was wondering if this is the correct way of applying boundary conditions.

Convert the above formula into matrix form

$\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{A_1}}&\vline& {{A_2}}\\
\hline
{{A_3}}&\vline& {{A_4}}
\end{array}} \right]\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{{r_1}}\\
{{r_n}}\\
\hline
{{v_1}}\\
{{r_2}}\\
{{v_2}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{r_{_{n - 1}}}}\\
{{v_{n - 1}}}\\
{{v_n}}
\end{array}} \right] = \left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
0\\
{10}\\
\hline
{\frac{{f\sin \omega {t_1}}}{m}}\\
{{v_2}}\\
{\frac{{f\sin \omega {t_2}}}{m}}\\
 \vdots \\
{{v_{_{n - 1}}}}\\
{\frac{{f\sin \omega {t_{n - 1}}}}{m}}\\
{\frac{{f\sin \omega {t_n}}}{m}}
\end{array}} \right]$

However, at this step, the matrix $A_4$ is not full rank, and ${v_1},{r_2}, \cdots ,{v_n}$ cannot be solved by the iterative method.

I was wondering if at which step the differential quadrature method was applied incorrectly. Is it because the given boundary conditions lead to multiple solutions for the above equation, so the matrix $A_4$ is not full rank. But I can use the bvp4c solver of the Matlab to integrate the above equations.